# Convolutionall Neural networks for 1 D data

Tags: python, tensorflow

Can we like use CNN for 1D data which are not images like for example a list of 9 real numbers which represent function values?? In this code I am using the 9 real number list as the training data. The problem involves calculating the numerical derivative at point 5th using different derivatives. The labels of this problem represents the method that is closest to the actual derivative.

```
from keras.utils import np_utils
import numpy as np
import random
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf

def calculation_of_labels(func,derf):
    f2f= (func[5]-func[4])/(0.125)
    f2b= (func[4]-func[3])/(0.125)
    f3=(func[5]-func[3])/(0.125*2)
    f4b=(2*func[5]+3*func[4]-6*func[3]+func[2])/(6*0.125)
    f4f= (-1*func[6]+6*func[5]-3*func[4]-2*func[3])/(6*0.125)
    f5=(-1*func[6]+8*func[5]-8*func[3]+func[2])/(0.125*12)
    f6b=(-3*func[6]+30*func[5]+20*func[4]-60*func[3]+15*func[2]-2*func[1])/(0.125*60)
    f6f=(2*func[7]-15*func[6]+func[5]-20*func[4]-30*func[3]+3*func[2])/(0.125*60)
    f7=(func[7]-9*func[6]+45*func[5]-45*func[3]+9*func[2]-1*func[1])/(0.125*60)
    f8f=(-3*func[8]+28*func[7]-126*func[6]+420*func[5]-105*func[4]-252*func[3]+42*func[2]-4*func[1])/(0.125*420)
    f8b=(4*func[7]-42*func[6]+252*func[5]+105*func[4]-420*func[3]+126*func[2]-28*func[1]+3*func[0])/(0.125*420)
    f9=(-3*func[8]+32*func[7]-168*func[6]+672*func[5]-672*func[3]+168*func[2]-32*func[1]+3*func[0])/(0.125*840)
    myList=[f2b,f2f,f3,f4b,f4f,f5,f6b,f6f,f7,f8b,f8f,f9]
    b=min(myList, key=lambda x:abs(x-derf))
    a=myList.index(b)
    return a

funvalue=[]
lab=[]
fun_der_mat=0

for number in range(0,300000):
    function=0
    fder=0
    Ak= random.uniform(1,5)
    xv=np.arange(0,1.1,0.125)
    for k in range(1,5):
        phi = random.uniform(0,1)
        function = function+ (Ak/k)*np.sin(2*np.pi*k*xv+ phi*2*np.pi)
        fder = fder+ (Ak)*2*np.pi*np.cos(2*np.pi*k*xv+ phi*2*np.pi)
        for j in range(0,9):
            function[j] = round(function[j],3)
            fder[j] = round(fder[j],3)        
    funvalue.append(function)
    lab.append(calculation_of_labels(function, fder[4]))

funvalue= np.array(funvalue)
funfinal= np.reshape(funvalue, (300000,9))
inputdata,Label = shuffle(funfinal,lab, random_state = 2)
train_data = [inputdata, Label]
x= tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,9])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 12])
#logs_path= '/tmp/check/'

(X,s)= (train_data[0],train_data[1])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, s, test_size = 0.2, random_state=4)
X_train= np.array(X_train)
X_test= np.array(X_test)

X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test= X_test.astype('float32')
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)####CHECK PLEASE 
learning_rate = 0.05

n_hidden_1 = 200 # 1st layer number of features
n_hidden_2 = 200 # 2nd layer number of features
n_hidden_3 = 200
n_input = 9 
n_classes = 12

def next_batch(index_receive, dat, labels):
    dat_shuffle = [dat[ i] for i in index_receive]
    labels_shuffle = [labels[ i] for i in index_receive]
    return np.asarray(dat_shuffle), np.asarray(labels_shuffle)

w1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([9, 200]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([200]))
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([200, 200]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([200]))
w3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([200, 200]))
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([200]))
wo = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([200, 12]))
bo = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([12]))

def multilayer_perceptron(x):
        layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, w1), b1)
        layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
        layer_1= tf.nn.dropout(layer_1,keep_prob)
        layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, w2),b2)
        layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)
        layer_2= tf.nn.dropout(layer_2,keep_prob)
        layer_3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, w3), b3)
        layer_3 = tf.nn.relu(layer_3)
        layer_3= tf.nn.dropout(layer_3,keep_prob)
        out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_3, wo) + bo
        return out_layer
pred = multilayer_perceptron(x)
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = pred, labels=y_))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,tf.float32))
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
batch_size = 5000
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for epoch in range(2000):
        index=np.arange(0,240000)
        np.random.shuffle(index)
        batch_count = 240000//batch_size + 1
        for j in range(batch_count):
                start = j*batch_size
                end_idx = start + batch_size
                if j == (batch_count - 1 ):
                        break
                swiped_index = index[start:end_idx]
                batch = next_batch(swiped_index, X_train,Y_train)
                optimizer.run(feed_dict={x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob : 0.5})
                # Display logs per epoch step
        if epoch % 100 == 0:
                train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
                print("step %d, Training accuracy %g" %( epoch, train_accuracy))

    print("Optimization Finished!")
    index_rec=np.arange(0,60000)
    np.random.shuffle(index_rec)
    swiped=index_rec[0:5000]
    batch1= next_batch(swiped,X_test,Y_test)
    print("test accuracy %g"%accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: batch1[0], y_: batch1[1], keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

Comment: The use of CNN is for 2D data in which the columns of the data have some sort of connection between them. You can use a DNN or a MLP in your case

Comment: @Sriram I have written a code for MLP but its not improving the accuracy.

Comment: the accuracy is around 15 percent and the cost is not decreasing